# get list of state_machine states

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

We are using state_machine ( https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine ) in a project and would like to offer a form with a select that lets us choose a state. (this is for searching, not for setting).
I can't seem to find a way to list out all the possible states? Surely there should be an automatic way of doing this, not having to hard-code a list of text somewhere.
Thanks!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Something like:

```
User.state_machine.states.map &:name
```

Answer (score 72):

Just to add to this (because I'm constantly searching for this answer, and I always come back to this page), if you are trying to list the states for a giving state machine, try this:

```
Discussion.state_machines[:name_of_state].states.map &:name
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much better.  The accepted answer only handles the defaults I guess, and I needed the states for my custom field "status".  Thanks again!

Comment: Make sure this line comes after the state machine declarations if using it in your class.

Answer (score 5):

If you name your state field differently , such as publish_status

```
Article.state_machines[:publish_status].states.map &:name
```

Comment: I wonder how you realized about it? Did you find it on the docs? Because I couldn't find it in there.