# Howto get all state_machine events from model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

Is it possible to get all events from a model class? I want to filter a list by events.

There was a [similar question on mailinglist](http://groups.google.com/group/pluginaweek-talk/browse_thread/thread/39e785cee0ba9309/cee2f2713f65c2ae) about all transitions.

I am using https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

Comment: Ok, i found a previous question answering this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138437/get-list-of-state-machine-states

Comment: I have to correct myself. Answer on above questions gives all transitions and not the events.

Comment: It would probably depend on which state machine software that you're using.

Comment: Right, i have extended my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right on the github page you link to it shows the API methods for:

```
vehicle.state_events  # shows all the events possible from the current state
```

and

```
vehicle.state_paths.events # shows all the events for an object
```

Comment: Yes, but this is for a specific object, not the model class

Comment: "Vehicle.new.state_events" or "Vehicle.new.state_paths.events" then... there's probably a more direct way, if you look through the API you linked, it does seem to be that each object gets an "events" collection. But I don't use that state machine, so I can't say more than that.

Comment: Here are some more informations about this topic: https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/issues/165

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer for some reason takes a few seconds for me to compute. I guess this happens if you have a lot of states.

What works for me is:

```
Invoice.state_machines[:state].events.map(&:name)
```

In my case the class name is `invoice` and the state_machine is named `state`.

Answer (score 0):

*edit 2014: this list states, not events*

This is how I did it, to only list the keys

```
def self.membership_states
  self.state_machines[:membership_status].states.map(&:name)
end

$ User.membership_states
> [:applied, ...
```

Comment: The OP asked for the events, not the sates. So I guess this won't work.

Comment: @Hendrik, yeah, you're right, and those aren't the same :D been a while, do you think I should delete ?

Comment: Nope, just keep contributing :)