# get list of final state_machine states

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

There is a method in the StateMachine library [to get the list of states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138437/get-list-of-state-machine-states):

```
ModelName.state_machines[:name_of_state].states.map &:name
```

or

```
ModelName.state_machines.states.map &:name
```

when the name of the attribute containing state is the default "state".

However, I was wondering whether there's a way to find the final statemachine, since if you draw them with

```
rake state_machine:draw FILE=model.rb CLASS=ModelName
```

the final states are double-circled.
I was not able to get it from the rake task's source at first sight.

Getting the initial states seems to be easy:

```
ModelName.state_machines[:name_of_state].states.select(&:initial).map(&:name)
```

**Update**:

Oh, drats!  It is as easy as:

```
ModelName.state_machines[:name_of_state].states.select(&:final?).map(&:name)
```

Left here for future Googlers!